# Operation timed out despite socket.setdefaulttimeout()

Tags: python, python-3.x, imap, imaplib

I'm trying to connect to an imap server:

```
mailbox = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host=server, port=port)
```

This results in a timeout:

> [Errno 60] Operation timed out

So I tried to increase the timeout:

```
import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(4000)
mailbox = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host=server, port=port)
```

But still the same error. It appears around 115 seconds. What could be the cause for the timeout? I guess it has to be something on the server side then?

Comment: Firewall?  Are you able to connect to the server with a socket tool? (socat, openssl s_client, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I learned that one can scan the ports (I used [nmap](http://nmap)), turns out the port was closed.

[socat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/socat) and [openssl s_client](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/openssl-s_client.html) as mentioned in the comments are useful tools as well for finding out what's going on.